# Powershell silent install

Tags: powershell, installation, silent-installer

I would like to know how to install something, anything, such as notepad with powershell unattended.  i really cant find much on this online.  I renamed the exe file to notepad.exe and threw it on the root of c.  this doesnt work but its what I got:
    Start-Process c:\notepad.exe -ArgumentList "/q" -Wait

I cant get anything from the powershell help.  this still makes me have to accept and click through the install process, im trying to avoid that.  any help and educating me too would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Powershell can run anything you want. All installers have specific ways of promoting silent installation. `Notepad.exe` is not an installer.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the install program with /? as a switch, it shows you the answer - either /passive for an unattended install, or /q for a silent install.

Answer (score 0):

That totally depends on the installer you're trying to use.  Unfortunately, Windows installers aren't all .msi packages, and the executables all have different switches.

You could check out [Chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org), which certainly has loads of silent install scripts for installing apps (and everything's done with PowerShell scripts), including [packages for Notepad++ and Notepad2, etc.](http://chocolatey.org/packages?q=notepad)

Answer (score 0):

you can install a program in silent mode with a vbs script :

Here is an example :

> Option Explicit
>   Dim MaCmd
>   MaCmd = "Start /Wait D:\Soft\file.exe /S"&_
>   " & echo Soft was fully installed > LogInstall.txt & Start LogInstall.txt"
>   Call Executer(MaCmd,0)
>   '**************************************************************************************************
>   Function Executer(StrCmd,Console)
>       Dim ws,MyCmd,Resultat
>       Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
>   'Value 0 for hide Ms-Dos
>       If Console = 0 Then
>           MyCmd = "CMD /C " & StrCmd & " "
>           Resultat = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,True)
>           If Resultat = 0 Then
>   'MsgBox "Success"
>           Else
>               MsgBox "an unknown error occurred"
>           End If
>       End If
>   'Value 1 for show MS-Dos
>       If Console = 1 Then
>           MyCmd = "CMD /K " & StrCmd & " "
>           Resultat = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,False)
>           If Resultat = 0 Then
>   'MsgBox "Success"
>           Else
>               MsgBox "an unknown error occurred"
>           End If
>       End If
>       Executer = Resultat
>   End Function
>   '****************************************************************************************************